# Imagen desalineado en Toolbar de Android Studio

Tags: android, toolbar

En mi app necesito inserta una imagen en el Toolbar, la imagen se inserta pero no se ubica adecuadamente, ademas de la imagen, en el Toolbar tengo dos iconos, como puedo hacer para que la imagen y los iconos este adecuadamente alineados en una sola fila

Asi es como se esta biendo mi Toolbar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el MainActivity he deshabilitado el titulo:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

y asi he adiconado la iamgen dentro del Toolbar :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intentantaste agregar la propiedad `android:scaleType` en el xml? Por ahi utilizando `fitXY` se acomode la imagen.

Leyendo esta [documentacion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#attr_android:scaleType) puedas encontrar cual es el valor que necesites para tu caso.